# NullPointerException on main() in Condition

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to run this: `PGDirTestController.performExecute();` which calls the `performExecute()` method, which should fall into the `else{}` in `performExecute()` which finally calls `callUSInterface();`

Unfortunately, this is throwing a NullPointerException of:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.XX.commerce.bes.member.test.commands.XXGetProgramGuideDirectTestControllerCmdImpl.performExecute(XXGetProgramGuideDirectTestControllerCmdImpl.java:51)
    at com.XX.commerce.bes.member.test.commands.XXGetProgramGuideDirectTestControllerCmdImpl.main(XXGetProgramGuideDirectTestControllerCmdImpl.java:199)
```

**Line:51 of XXGetProgramGuideDirectTestControllerCmdImpl** is:

```
if (getRequestProperties().getString(XXMessagingConstants.STORE_ID).equals(XXMessagingConstants.DE_STORE_ID)) {
```

**Line:199 of XXGetProgramGuideDirectTestControllerCmdImpl** is:

```
PGDirTestController.performExecute();
```

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

I am still pretty new to java.

Comment: PGDirTestController must be null ... recheck that it is getting initialized as expected.

Comment: cant you just use the debugger and look after the nullpointer?

Comment: Is `getRequestProperties()!=null` and `getRequestProperties().getString(XXMessagingConstants.STORE_ID)!=null` ?

Comment: A good practice is to always put the constants at the start of equals etc. This both avoids NPEs and makes it clear what is being compared since the first portion will always be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this expression returns `null`:

```
getRequestProperties().getString(XXMessagingConstants.STORE_ID)
```

You should probably add a separate check for that scenario. Either you turn the condition around:

```
if (XXMessagingConstants.DE_STORE_ID.equals(getRequestProperties().getString(XXMessagingConstants.STORE_ID))
```

as described by @Stefan Beike. This would make this null case as a not equal value. Or maybe you want to do something total different, when you get `null`, so you might do something like

```
if (getRequestProperties().getString(XXMessagingConstants.STORE_ID) == null)
    log.wanr("request parameter is Null, this shouldn't be this way");
else if (XXMessagingConstants.DE_STORE_ID.equals(getRequestProperties().getString(XXMessagingConstants.STORE_ID)) 
    ....
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the "seperate check" ? Thanks for addressing the question here.

Answer (score 1):

IMO it is better to use the `if-condition` like that:

```
if (XXMessagingConstants.DE_STORE_ID.equals(getRequestProperties().getString(XXMessagingConstants.STORE_ID)) {
```

that is Null saved!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this doesn't solve the issue, but probably is better for performance. Thanks.

Comment: If that doesn't solve it then your getRequestProperties itself is returning null.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the NPE by interchanging the strings that you are checking.

```
if (XXMessagingConstants.DE_STORE_ID.equals(getRequestProperties().getString(XXMessagingConstants.STORE_ID)) {
```

For more information, do check the API reference http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html for equals() method.